# IE 11 performance in robot framework

Tags: xpath, robotframework, selenium-iedriver

The performance of my scripts is very slow when running on IE11. Some of my scripts run on chrome in 2-3 mins and that takes more than 25 minutes on IE. I am using Robot Framework and most of my locators are xpath. My application does not have ID locators for the elements. I tried switching to CSS for experimental purpose but that improved the performance by little margin.
I understand that since IE does not have a native xpath engine, IEdriverserver uses wicked-good-xpath for parsing. This xpath library is supposed to be the fastest.
Is there any other modification/enhancement I can do to improve the performance of my scripts.

Comment: The performance is awful  when I am traversing the DOM over a list of elements. such as fetching text from a list of span, div etc

Answer (score 1):

If You are using `64-bit` IEdriverserver, You need to replace it with `32-bit` of IEdriverserver because **64-bit of IEdriverserver is very very slow for the execution.**

*IE driver to determine the root cause. When you are running IE 10 or higher on a 64-bit
version of Windows, by default the process which hosts the containing window that includes
the browser chrome (address bar, navigation buttons, menus, etc.) is a 64-bit process.
The process which hosts the window where content is actually rendered (within each
tab) is a 32-bit process.*

*Some notes. Careful readers will have already realized that this means that even when
you are running 64-bit Windows, you're likely using a 32-bit version of IE to render
the content. This is a powerful argument for continuing to use the 32-bit version of
the IE driver for IE 10 and above: you're not actually running against a 64-bit version
of IE.*

If you insist that you must run the 64-bit version of IEDriverServer.exe,  you can disable native events by setting the `nativeEvents`
capability to false using whatever mechanism your language binding provides for this.

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: Thanks Saurabh, I did that. But the performance did not improve much. The time taken for the execution in chrome and Firefox is around 3 minutes but the IE is is about 17 minutes. The script mostly traverses through a table to fetch data.

Comment: @user3262242 I would suggest you try to use cssSelector mostly if possible because IE is much slower with the xpath...:)

Comment: It does not help much when I run tests on IE with tests written in Robot Framework